# add upload image field in product custom options for magento

Tags: magento

I am facing a problem while adding multiple images in custom option at the time of adding a product.

How can I add multiple image in custom option in magento?

Please suggest me how can i do like this. thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: this question related to programming sir .. because this is possible to do using programming.

I am working on magento 1.9 version.I want to add a custom image field in drop down of custom options. I added a text field using following guide 

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

Comment: this can be possible...will be tricky